# Change textbox text color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I have a textbox.When I click this I want to change text color style with javsacript.Before this I made succesfully this.When someone click the textbox textbox clear inner when blur textbox become old version.This code works for me now

```
<input id="kullanici_adi_text" type="text" name="kullanici_adi_text"    value="Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...') {this.value='';}  onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...'}"/>
```

But I want to change text color also and textbox border size when someone focus at this.The code is not working

```
<input id="kullanici_adi_text" type="text" name="kullanici_adi_text" value="Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...') {this.value=''; document.getElementById('kullanici_adi_text').style.color = 'blue';}"  onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...'; document.getElementById('kullanici_adi_text').style.color = #fff; }"/>
```

Comment: You appear to be missing quotes around your hexcode colour. You have this: `document.getElementById('kullanici_adi_text').style.color = #fff;` 

But it should be like this: 
`document.getElementById('kullanici_adi_text').style.color = '#fff';`

Comment: @AndyHenderson not working anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use quotas for color:

```
<input id="kullanici_adi_text" type="text"
   name="kullanici_adi_text"
   value="Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz..." 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...')
    {this.value='';
     this.style.color = 'blue';}"  
onblur="if(this.value=='')
    {this.value='Kullanıcı İsmini Giriniz...';
     this.style.color = '#ff0000';}"/>
```

And as a recomendation - it is better to sepatate javascript code from markup.

Comment: how can I give rgba it doesnt work => this.style.color='rgba(69,69,69,0.3)';

Comment: Please check a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4humesk7/1/ - this works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

this would work
`<input id="kullanici_adi_text" type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("kullanici_adi_text").style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById("kullanici_adi_text").style.color = "magenta";
document.getElementById("kullanici_adi_text").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("kullanici_adi_text").style.color = "lightblue";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Include jQuery library in your document.

2.Include this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#kullanici_adi_text').focus(function(){
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
   }).focusout(function(){
       $(this).css('color', 'black');
   });
});
```